# Load byte on mips32

Tags: mips32

I'm starting with mips32 and I'm getting stuck when trying to get a letter from a string to print it.  The code should get the string, print it character by character and when it finds an `i` print `iiing`.

```
.data
msg: .asciiz "testing"
i: .asciiz "iiing"

.text

.globl main

main:           
    la $t0, msg
    la $t1, i
    li $t2, 0
loop:
     bneq $t0, 105, end #$t0=i?
     lb $a0, ($t0)
     li $v0, 4
     syscall
     addi $t0, $t0, 1
     b loop

end:
     move $a0, $t1
     li $v0, 4
     syscall
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few problems.

1. You are comparing `$t0`, which is the *address* of the current character, not the character itself.  Move that test below the `lb` line and test against `$a0`.
2. `105` in ASCII is `E`, not `i`.  Try `151` (or to be more normal, `0x69`).
3. You want to compare with `beq`, not `bneq`.
4. Inside the loop, you should use syscall `11`, which prints a single character, rather than the current syscall `4` you're using, which prints a string.
5. Your program doesn't make an exit syscall (`10`) at the end.

You can look at [this link](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/lab/secondyear/spim/node8.html) for a list of syscalls.

Here's a complete working program for reference:

```
    .data

msg: .asciiz "testing"
i:   .asciiz "iiing"

    .text
    .globl main

main:           
    la $t0, msg
    la $t1, i
    li $t2, 0

loop:
    lb $a0, ($t0)
    beq $a0, 0x69, end
    li $v0, 11
    syscall
    addi $t0, $t0, 1
    b loop

end:
    move $a0, $t1
    li $v0, 4
    syscall
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Comment: actually, you are right, but making that modifications i still get an erro in the branch line, just in case i've missunderstood, did you mean like this?             loop:
       lb $a0, ($t0)
       bneq $a0, 0x69, end #$t0=i?       
    li $v0, 4
    syscall
    addi $t0, $t0, 1
    b loop

Comment: That looks close, but you probably want `beq`, now that I look closer.  You should probably also update the comment to match the operation you're doing (`$a0` vs. `$t0`).

Comment: yep, true, but it still doesnt detect the characters with lb, i mean it prints (null)null..iiing, any idea of why? sorry for so many stupid questions..

Comment: Does `syscall 4` print a string?  That would be a problem.  You need the syscall that prints characters.

Comment: OK, I just went and installed SPIM.  Updating answer now.

Comment: ok, now i get it, every program must end up with syscall 10, i thought it was just an option for programs that execute forever, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Happy to help - you can upvote & accept the answer, if you think it helped out.